# How to handle 4 websites with same core code on github?

Tags: github

**here is situation:**
I have a 4 websites, but all website share same code, only one difference is really style.css, sometimes images, or any minor changes in templates

**here is what I did:**
I've created a repo on github, so I have 4 branches, master,a ,b and c (each branch for each website).
at the beginning that solution was ok, but then I had to implement something let's say to master and then push it to a/b/c
probably it's lack of my understating of github but when I had to deploy  commit from master to a, I go to a branch directory(a) and I do

```
git pull origin master
```

well it doesn't not really work anymore, with different styles and other minor things I end up with a lot of conflicts, and it just does not feel right,
then I find out that I can use

```
git cherry-pick
```

but now matter what I do, it always response with 'bad revision xxx'

I am looking for proper way, of handling it,

Thanks.

Comment: Try having each website as its own repository and having the core as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). Or use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to pull the core in every time you deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create mountable-engines for same code

[mountable-engines](http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines)